What does "聞けど" mean? Is it a short version of some grammar?

人から時間を聞けど、もう何日も時計を見ていない。 時間の感覚が失われ、一秒が数時間に、または数時間が一瞬のようにも感じられる。

I know what the sentence means but I don't understand the first part of it. he says he can't tell the time but...? As far I can see from the scene, he has no way to tell or ask the time to anyone.

聞けど is example of form variously called Contrasting conjunction (in Wiktionary), Concessive (by Bjarke Frellesvig (2010)), Concessive Converb (by Alexander Vovin (2020)).
Meaning of this form: "although, even though, even if, even when" + VERB.
This form was supposedly still used in Late Middle Japanese (1200 - 1600), but is archaic in Modern Japanese.
This form diachronically consists of 2 or 3 suffixes:

Suffix -e ~ -ure of [已然形]{いぜんけい} / Realis (Wiktionary) / Exclamatory (Bjarke Frellesvig (2010)) / Evidential (Alexander Vovin (2020))
Variant -e is used after consonant stems. Variant -ure is used after vowel stems, with usual rules of vowel elision.

Suffix -do of Contrasting conjunction (Wiktionary), Concessive (Bjarke Frellesvig (2010)), Concessive Converb (Alexander Vovin (2020))

Optional suffix -mo (assumed to come from emphatic particle mo)


Examples:

聞けど = kikedo = kik- + -e + -do

逃ぐれど = niguredo = nige- + -ure + -do
Modernized form after shift from 二段活用 to 一段活用:

逃げれど = nigeredo = nige- + -ure + -do

見れど = miredo = mi- + -ure + -do

すれど = suredo = se- + -ure + -do

來れど = kuredo = ko- + -ure + -do


[已然形]{いぜんけい} / Realis / Exclamatory / Evidential was an independent verbal form, but came out of usage even earlier than Contrasting conjunction / Concessive / Concessive Converb, but remained as base for formation of 2 forms with additional suffixes, form discussed here and form with -ba suffix (now one of conditional forms).

In late Late Middle Japanese independent conjunction / particle けれども developed from this verbal suffix (which later developed shortened variants けれど, けども, けど).

Sorry but does this mean like I can ask? I could ask? I don't understand the  nuance

@JBean 「人から時間を聞けど」 is like modern 「人から時間を聞くけれども」. Without knowing more context, I think that this 「人から時間を聞けど」 can be translated as "Although I hear time from somebody" or "Although I ask for time from somebody".

聞けど is 聞け (the 已然形{いぜんけい} of 聞く) and the particle ど which just means "けど".
See this answer.
